# Git: don't touch on specific folders

Tags: git

I need to make commits but i need to ignore some folders (production server).

I've tested the .gitignore but with this, he delete the folders.

How to resolve?

Comment: *"I've tested the .gitignore but with this, he delete the folders."* -- adding lines into `.gitignore` does not persuade Git to delete anything. The *new* files whose paths match the rules in `.gitignore` are not added automatically by `git add`. Nothing else happens. The files that are already tracked by Git are not affected by the new rules added to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` so the files are still tracked in the origin repo, but locally it will never be shown as changed.

Comment: <file> can be a folder?

Comment: afair yes, it's just a path and used to skip checking of files on slow systems. so your case is not it's intended use but should work too. normally you should use .gitignore